# $n$ linearly independent rows of Vandermonde matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Consider the "infinite" Vandermonde matrix 
$$
V (x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n) =
\begin{pmatrix}
  1      & x_1    & x_1^2  & \cdots & x_1^{n-1} & x_1^n & x_1^{n+1} & \cdots \\
  1      & x_2    & x_2^2  & \cdots & x_2^{n-1} & x_2^n & x_1^{n+1} & \cdots \\
  1      & x_3    & x_3^2  & \cdots & x_3^{n-1} & x_3^n & x_1^{n+1} & \cdots \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots    & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots \\
  1      & x_n    & x_n^2  & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} & x_n^n & x_n^{n+1} & \cdots
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with distinct $x_1, \dots, x_n$. It is well-known that if we pick the first $n$ columns, then they span the whole space.

I was wondering, if the same holds true if one picks arbitrary (not necessary consecutive) $n$ columns in the above "infinite" Vandermonde matrix. I looked at simple examples and they suggest that this is true. Is there a nice way of proving this?

Comment: “They span the whole space”: what space are you talking about?

Comment: I am sorry, I ment $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about a [Generalized Vanderrmonde Matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedVandermondeMatrix.html), so the determinant will always be positive and the matrix is always invertible.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of a simple counterexample.

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
x &x^3\\
-x &(-x)^3\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

If all the columns are an even power or all are an odd power, then $x$ and $-x$ rows are linearly dependent.

Also, if any x = 0, any minor including that row will be singular.

Answer (score 0):

Another counterexample would be for complex variables any real multiple of a n:th root of unity $$rx = r e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$$

then $$\begin{bmatrix} (rx)^n& (rx)^{2n} \\(rx)^{n+k}&(rx)^{2n+k}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} r^n& r^{2n} \\r^{n+k}x^k&r^{2n+k}x^{k}\end{bmatrix}$$

and we see the second row is $r^kx^k$ times the first.

For real matrices the only possibility is even and odd because they are the only roots of unity there but for complex we can have any integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong quite often. First of all let me reformulate the condition that $n$ columns of such matrix are linearly dependent. Suppose the columns numbers are $i_1, \dots, i_n$ and coefficients of linear dependence are $c_1,dots, c_n$. Construct polynomial
$$ p(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k x^{i_k}.$$
Then existence of linear dependence for this columns with coefficients $c_i$ is equivalent to system: $p(x_i)=0$ for all $i$. Thus finding polynomial p(x) leads to linear dependence for columns of $V(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, where $x_i$ are roots of p(x).

Such polynomial $p(x)$ is of special form. It's degree should be greater or equal than $n$ and it should have at most $n$ nonzero coefficients. But of course there are a lot of such polynomials even with distinct real roots.
For example, take any positive distinct $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$. Then take $\lambda = -\sum x_i$ and construct
$$ p(x) = (x-\lambda)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (x-x_i).$$
This one has distinct real roots and is of the form $p(x)= x^n + c x^{n-2}+ \dots$ thus having at most $n$ nonzero coefficients. This leads to linear dependence for columns of $V(x_1\dots,x_{n-1},\lambda)$. Columns $1,\dots,n-1, n+1$.